# How to pass all but the first argument to a second bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that executes another bash script with all but the first argument, so I can't use:

> bash abc.sh "$@"

because it will also pass the first argument which I don't want. How can i remove the first argument?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can remove the first argument with a `shift`:

```
shift #same as: shift 1
bash abc.sh "$@"
```

(In `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`, you can also use `"${@:2}"` without modifying the `"$@"` array, but `shift` will work in any POSIX shell.)

Comment: Yeah seems like `dash` doesn't like that notation.